# sys_config.h and retcode.h and .... what is compiler or OS used?

Tags: c

I have some code and try to compile it, but I can't.
What compiler or OS used?
These files are used in it

```
#include <sys_config.h>
#include <retcode.h>
#include <types.h>
#include <osal/osal.h>
#include <api/libc/alloc.h>
#include <api/libc/printf.h>
#include <api/libc/string.h>
#include <hal/hal_gpio.h>
#include <hld/hld_dev.h>
#include <hld/nim/nim_dev.h> 
#include <hld/nim/nim.h>
#include <hld/nim/nim_tuner.h>
#include <bus/i2c/i2c.h>
#include <hld/dmx/dmx_dev.h>
#include <hld/dmx/dmx.h>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. It's code that presumably you wrote or copied from somewhere. So perhaps you can fill us in a bit on the background, what exactly have you tried and what exactly is the error.

Comment: Thank you. I wanna to run a device (tuner). I have some codes (include .h .c) but I don't konw what compiler and OS are used.

Comment: I try to compile on visual studio and some error happaned.

Comment: Please think about what you are asking. You have presented a random, incomplete snippet of code with no information on where it comes from, no detailed description of  how you have attempted to compile this and no description of what the actual error messages are. It's unlikely anyone will know what you are talking about. Wouldn't it make more sense to go back to where you got this code and look for the build instructions?

Answer (score 0):

Googling some of the header names, it looks like you are trying to compile a Linux kernel module. That means the compiler will be gcc at whatever version is recommended for the kernel you are compiling against. The OS will be Linux + the kernel development kit.